Ошибка Selenium - python
помогите пожалуйста разобраться с Selenium
Мой код:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get("https://rakhat-nsk.ru/?ysclid=lw5yze7y11818676398")

logo = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "logo")

print(logo)

Консоль выдаёт вот такую ошибку:
[12712:23404:0514/130352.869:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1063)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[12712:23404:0514/130417.098:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1063)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[12712:23404:0514/130421.210:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1063)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
Работает минут 5, выводя эту ошибку.
Только потом делает вывод logo. В чём проблема, помогите пожалуйста

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7febff7bcadd4c174bd8b6ceb86b8f2c", element="f.2D11D76775D91FFC2D3A938F682FE5F3.d.7F83E4B6A4FF4E4635E1B53E2111AC02.e.88")>
Выводит это

Проблема с ssl сертификатом сайта, попробуйте такой вариант:
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)

driver.get("https://rakhat-nsk.ru/?ysclid=lw5yze7y11818676398")


Ничего не изменилось, выводится та же ошибка

Нет, теперь такой вывод
[27848:18360:0514/135155.634:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101

@супермэн Попробуйте заменить ключ --ignore-ssl-errors на --ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list
